# Are you able in Python to name functions as numbers such as 1 2 3 4 etc

Tags: python

I would like to call functions from the items in my option_list using the first character(index*) in their name which would be 1 or 2
problem is functions don't like being called numbers even if I  put "1" or "2"
how would I go about this?

```
def main():
    print(option_list := ["1.data", "2.stratified sampling"])
    user_select = input("Type your selection!..\n").lower()
    for value in option_list:
        if user_select == value[0]:
            eval(value)


#  functions for specification
def 1():
    print("data")


main()
```

Comment: its better to name functions what the general purpose of the function is. It will be better and/ or more helpful later down the road.

Comment: You can't start a function name with a number. Give it a useful name instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this naming scheme?

Comment: i understand python has its own conventions on what to do and what not to do but with this program its for my own personal use to study maths so im fine with it being unconventional, if there is any possible way to do it i would love to know if not ill try figure something else out

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover agreed, but the `1()` isn't even **valid** python syntax.

Comment: is there a way to make it valid?

Comment: there is, but why would you want a function named 1?

Comment: @rv.kvetch thats what i meant

Comment: The usual workaround is to prefix the digit with an underscore: i.e. `def _1():`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add some characters in front of your function and pretty sure you'll still achieve what you want, though not sure what it is

```py
def main():
    print(option_list := ["1.data", "2.stratified sampling"])
    user_select = input("Type your selection!..\n").lower()
    for value in option_list:
        if user_select == value[0]:
            eval(f"func{value[0]}()")


#  functions for specification
def func1():
    print("data")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a dictionary that links the number to your function:

```
dictionary = {
1: data,
2: stratified_sampling
}
```

Then, you can call it accessing that dictionary and the number:

```
dictionary[index]()
```

The whole program woud look like something like this:

```
def data():
    print("data")

def stratified_sampling():
    print("stratified sampling")

dictionary = {
    1: data,
    2: stratified_sampling
}

selection = int(input("Select the option\n"))

if selection in dictionary.keys():
    dictionary[selection]()
```

Comment: Thank you as well, my dictionary skills aren't very good but I will have a look at this

Comment: You can use a list as well, just keep in mind that the index in a list starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Define your functions with useful names:

```
def data():
    print("data")


def hello():
    print("hello")


def say_something():
    print("something")
```

You can put the functions into a list:

```
functions = [data, hello, say_something]
```

When asking the user to choose a function, print out all of their names:

```
print([f.__name__ for f in functions])
```

Ask for the index of the function they want to use:

```
i = int(input("Type the index of the function you want\n"))
```

Then call that function:

```
functions[i]()
```

Putting them in a list may be better than a dictionary if you are only numbering them since indexing is inherent to a list.

Comment: very interesting way to do it and lets me use conventional naming thank you